# exponents or logarithms in java?

Tags: java, drawing, graphing

I'm still relatively new here. Trying to post better questions and hopefully more feedback!

I'm trying to draw some lines representing isothermal (red lines) and adiabatic processes (dark lines) from thermodynamics. example from wiki http://bit.ly/1Qixotl

the equation for isotherm is pressure(Y) * volume(X) = constant (temperature)
so I drew my lines by defining Y = constant/X , and then using drawline commands to find points for those curves...I think those came out alright.

I'm stuck on the adiabatic lines...the equation for that is almost the same, but has an exponent in the mix. Y * X^gamma = constant.. gamma is usually 1.67 but if I try higher values it should just make the dark curves slopes steeper.

I tried calling Y = constant / X^gamma, but should I be using logarithms instead?

Any help appreciated.

```
   //ISOTHERMS
   //i = x axis; j = y axis;
  // for values 1 - 350
  // plot y values from isothermal equation -- P*V = constant T
 // j = k/i

  int k1 = 5000;
  //int k1 = 1500;
    //int k1 = 15000;
       //int k2 = 20000;
       int k2 = 15000;
       //int k2 = 30000;

  g.setColor(Color.red);
  for( int i = 1; i < 350; i++) 
  {
    int j1 = k1/i;
    int j2 = k2/i;
    //if(j1 < 350) 
        g.drawLine(i+50, j1+50, i+50, j1+50);
    //if(j2 < 350) 
        g.drawLine(i+50, j2+50, i+50, j2+50);

  }

    //ADIABATS
  //P*V^gamma = constant T
  double gamma = 1.67;

 for( int m = 1; m < 500; m++) 
 {

   // int h1 = (int) (1400000/(Math.pow(m,1.97)));
   int h1 = (int) (1000000/(Math.pow(m,2)));
    //int h2 = (int) (3500000/(Math.pow(m,1.97)));
   int h2 = (int) (2400000/(Math.pow(m,2)));
    //if(j1 < 350) 
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawLine(m+50, h1+50, m+50, h1+50);
    //if(j2 < 350) 
        g.drawLine(m+50, h2+50, m+50, h2+50);



  }
```

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI7Qh.png)

Comment: I don't quite get your question. " ... if I try higher values it should just make the dark curves slopes steeper" - is that it? Do you mean it doesn't produce the results you're getting? Did you do some debugging to check the values are alright? Can you provide an example of what you'd expect and what you get instead?

Comment: I'm also not sure why you're using `drawLine()` to draw pixels. Wouldn't you want to draw a line from (m,h1(m)) to (m+1,h1(m+1)), i.e. calculate the y coordinates for m and m + 1 and draw a line in between?

Comment: this seems to be a math/physics question rather than a programming question...

Comment: Logarithmic plots are really meant for analyzing experimental data and _finding_ gamma. There's no reason why you shouldn't plot Y as a function of X